# jQuery converts <br/> to <br>, why?

Tags: jquery, object

I have some html code loaded into a page and then converted to an object for further handling. The loaded text contains `<br/>` tags fine but after the object conversion these are changed to `<br>`, very strange. Any clues to why? The page is html5.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"load.php",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var $html = $(data);
        }
});
```

Comment: can you show us what load.php returns? dump the content of `data` please.

Comment: because in HTML5 there is no such thing as `<tag/>`, only void tags, which don't need the `/` closing mark, or *normal* tags, which require explicit `</tag>` closing tag.

Comment: The HTML is _fixed_ by the browser. No worries there.

Comment: What are you guys talking about? <br/> is perfectly valid HTML5. What it's *not* valid, is HTML 4 and older.

Comment: Alright now I understand. Perhaps I have a complicated setup: 1. My page is in html. 2. Want to load Xhtml valid code for manipulation on the html page. 3. want to return part of the html code to valid xhtml. The best of course was if the whole page was in xhtml but it is an old code...Will try to replace <br> to <br/>.

Comment: @Kevin Lindmark: That's indeed complicated. XHTML serialization is not trivial. It will be too broad to cover in a single Q&A.

Comment: @KevinLindmark it's not that hard actually, but your present question really didn't ask for it. An [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) will serialize your DOM to XHTML, if your elements were created using the XHTML nameSpaceURI (default for `createElement` in an HTML doc) https://jsfiddle.net/gp2gukhe/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your answer. My problem is that I have xhtml in a string and want to insert this into a html5 page without changing the xhtml formatting (for example removing closing tag). As I understand you answer this is for going from DOM to XHTML. Is there a solution for going from string to DOM while preserving XHTML?

Comment: No, once parsed your markup doesn't exists anymore. But I don't see the problem: HTML5 parsers will happily accept your XHTML markup, and you will be able to extract an XHTML valid markup from the HTML5 document.